# very strange behavior with __repr__ function

Tags: python, class, repr

I have a class with a `__repr__` method.  Something like

```
class foo:

   def __init__(self):
      ...

   def bar(self):
      ...

   def barnone(self):
      ...

   def __repr__(self):
      ...
```

Let's say I instantiate it in an object a.  Now, `__repr__` is then triggered and shoots out output whenever I type a plus a function name plus an open parenthesis:

```
>>> a = foo()
>>> a = bar(  # and now, before I can do anything, __repr__ right here gives output!
#   __repr__ output
>>> a = bar(  # thank goodness it gives me back the command line so I can continue typing
```

So I can still work with the class, but this is really annoying and very curious.  Anyone seen this before?

I am running python 3.x with Spyder in Anaconda, if that matters.

Comment: I don't understand what's going on. This is maybe some IDE issue, not something to do with python itself.

Comment: I agree this is probably some IDE issue, but it might be triggered by something in your code. Please provide a complete, minimal example of a class that produces the behavior.